# does InnoDB Crash on abnormal shutdown

Tags: php, mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I have built a small application with MySQL. Database Type is InnoDB. And it's hosted on some server. I am facing database crash so many times. When I asked reason from hosting provider they said to me:

> The problem was caused by an InnoDB database corruption which required a rebuild of all InnoDB tables. Some databases didn't rebuild properly though such as yours and it required to be fixed manually. That is what I did. No changes are required to be done from your end. We do not expect the problem to happen again anytime soon. We apologize for the inconvenience caused.

I told them I must have to use InnoDB because I need primary and foreign key relationship  which is with InnoDB. Now they are saying:

> Well that is correct, MyISAM does not support foreign keys. Actually InnoDB based tables are prone to get corrupt if MySQL is abnormally shutdown e.g. in case of a hard reboot or so. MyISAM instead is more reliable and repairing its tables are easy.

My QUESTION:
InnoDB based tables are prone to get corrupt if MySQL is abnormally shutdown, is this correct?

Comment: MyISAM is prone to that as well. If MySQL doesn't finish writing to either InnoDB or MyISAM - tables will get corrupt. It's the same with food - forget to cook it long enough - it sucks. Changing the meal from A to B isn't less prone to bad preparation. What should concern you is *why* the abnormal shutdown happens. Your host, to put it bluntly, sucks - get a better hosting provider (smells to me like imminent HDD failure at their end).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming default MySQL settings they're plain wrong.

But if you:

- disable double write buffer
- disable page checksums
- innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit <> 1
- enable write-back cache policy w/o a battery
- ... *list can be continued*

you will get InnoDB that is corruption prone indeed.